# Installing IPcop with an established Ubuntu installation

Tags: networking

I have installed IPcop as instructed from a CD made from their iso. The installation goes on a separate hard drive. When I boot my machine, IPcop comes up and loads then gives me a command line.

How do I get Ubuntu to load from another drive from this command line or have I done something wrong?

I am a hardware person and understand IP address and have built the computer I am using. I just need help from a keyboard person to tell me how to get to Ubuntu after IPcop loads.

BTW, this is a dual boot machine along with Windows 7 but Ubuntu is the default until I installed IP cop.

I can boot Ubuntu via changing the boot lineup in the BIOS of the mother board, but then IPcop doesn't boot.

Answer (score 2):

IPCop is a different OS like Ubuntu or Windows.  So it needs its own computer to run on.  It is meant to be run on any old computer you have lying around, plugged into the network and then run as an appliance without keyboard or screen attached.

For more information: [RTFM](http://www.ipcop.org/2.0.0/en/admin/html/)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtualization. If you create virtual machine in Ubuntu and run IpCop inside it, IpCop and Ubuntu will work together and IpCop won't disturb you.